# Why is exec() silently discarding bytes?

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec, implode, passthru

After a lot of struggling, I found out some behavior I can't explain / solve, so asking here for help. On our server (*Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with PHP 7.0.30*), we're using some tools outside of the 'httpdocs', which are called using [`exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to get their outputs. In this case, it's a QRCode-generator.

Some of the QR-codes however, won't be displayed. We got an output from the tool (*outputting data of a PNG*), but when we show it as an image, it appears to be broken for some reason.

After a lot of debugging I found out the result sometimes differs 1 or 2 bytes from the output of the tool.

I did my last debugging using the QR-code below (*12345*), which is a file of 240 bytes. However, when outputting it eventually, the length appears to be 239 bytes, so we lost a byte somewhere?

[image: Example QR-code]

I found out using [`exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), we're creating an array of the output. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array, so implode() to glue the array back to a string, like below:

```
<?php

$cmd = 'cat qr.png';
$output = array();
$exit_code = 0;

exec($cmd, $output, $exit_code);

if($exit_code === 0)
{
    header ("Content-type: image/png;");
    print implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
}
die();
```

But for some reason, a byte is lost in this process? I already tried some other solutions using [`shell_exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) (*but no return_var here, so we can't check validate the proces...*)

```
<?php

$command = 'cat qr.png';

$output = shell_exec($command);
if($output !== null)
{
    header ("Content-type: image/png;");
    print $output;
}
die();
```

... and using [`passthru()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) (*but this outputs the contents directly, which isn't desired. Output-buffering like in the example below isn't possible in the actual code...*)

```
<?php

$command = 'cat qr.png';
$return_var = 0;

ob_start();
passthru($command, $return_var);

if($return_var === 0)
{
    header ("Content-type: image/png;");
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    print $output;
}
die();
```

So far, the [`exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)-function always worked pretty well for us, resulting in a $return_var **AND** $output, but now I'm losing bytes. I already tried some variants of the PHP_EOL, we're now using as glue (*\n, \r and \n\r*), but with the first 2 line-endings, I still only got 239 bytes and with the last one, I end up with 241 bytes, so 1 byte to much.

Why am I losing a byte here? What is the correct way to convert the $output-array back into a string? Is there a way to get the 240-bytes output back by imploding the array? Or are there other functions I haven't found yet to execute a command which will give me the output as well as the return_var?

Comment: I strongly suspect something funky related to line endings is going on. Did you compare the broken received file with the correct one? Also, what about [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)?

Comment: Is there a difference in character encoding? Are the line-endings actually the same? Did you also try to look up any differences in the files? Also; if the images are exactly the same, you might not want to spend too much time debugging this on binary level.

Comment: inspecting the 2 files with a hex-viewer tool could give you a clue of that missing byte. Is it a line break? at the start? at the end? are the 2 files identical except of this byte?

Comment: In this case, the command is `cat qr.png`, but in the final solution, this is something like `/usr/local/bin/tools/generate-qr --input="12345"`, so readfile won't work. The encoding is the same, but I'm missing a line-end somewhere. When differencing the files, I see a upside down question mark in the working file (on 3rd line), but missing in the broken output. When using ord() from PHP, pasting the upside-down question-mark in a string, it tells me it's value 13 (Enter?).... So it's a newline I'm missing from exec(), but how do I get it back correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't get what is going on here.  How do you send your command line output to the client after imploding it with line breaks as `Content-type: image/png;` ? does your tool generate the QR-code as text outputted in the command line in form of symbols like this [▄█▄](https://www.messletters.com/en/text-art/) or generates an image binary file and save it in the file system ?

Comment: @Accountantم The tool for creating the QR-code (outputting a PNG) was formerly placed inside the httpdocs, getting the images with a cUrl-request and embedding them into an HTML e-mail using src='data:...'. But we want to remove load of the server, so instead of using cUrl, we want to create the QR-code directly on the server (no requests/Apache) and using the output from the shell-command to embed the generated PNG. But for some reason, after imploding the output from exec() we seam to loose data. Using a hex-viewer, I found out it was 0D (dec. 13, newline) missing in the broken image/output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual entry for `exec`, the function returns the last line of output. Whether that last line is also included as the last element of `$output` is unclear.

But more importantly the the manual states:

> Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array.

I would guess that this is per-element of the array (i.e. per-line of your output), but either way, your whitespace will be significant here, because you're not dealing with text - all the bytes are important and meaningful here. Remember, whitespace doesn't just mean `\n`. It can also mean `\t` or  (a space), for example.

In the event that a line ends with `F\t\n` (a capital F, or any other non-whitespace character, a tab, then a newline), both whitespace characters would be stripped from the end. When doing your `implode` operation, you might be putting the `\n` back, but you'll never know about the `\t` that was stripped.

The key thing to realise here is that **`exec` is expecting to be dealing with plain text not raw binary data**.

I would suggest that instead of using `cat qr.png`, you use `base64 qr.png` to encode the binary data into an ASCII string, then decode it in PHP with `base64_decode`. If you're not going to be using `cat` in reality, you can still pipe the output of your QR-generating command through `base64` like this: `generate-qr-png |base64`. There shouldn't be any significant whitespace in that situation, so nothing would get munged by `exec`.

Comment: It is indeed a whitespace problem. I guess a line end with a tab or something is the problem here. I hoped glueing the output from `exec` back together would result into the same result, but there's a difference between, causing broken files.

Base64 encoding and decoding it seams to solve the issue, thanks! With `|base64` I get the right output. Because it'll be an embedded image into an e-mail, the base64_decode isn't even necessary (did an encode when putting the impage into src='data:...', but this is now done by the command already :)

Comment: Sounds like it was meant to be :) Please do mark the answer as accepted then if it's solved your problem. Glad I could help!